# Swap multiple tokens at once

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain

I have the following code that swaps ETH (or BNB in may case on the BSC testnet) for a specific token:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.1;

import "https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IPancakeRouter02.sol";



contract UniswapExample {
  address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3 ; //Router for pancake

  IPancakeRouter02 public uniswapRouter;
  
   //Store addresses
  //address[] tokens = new address[](2);
  
  //address private usdt = 0x7ef95a0FEE0Dd31b22626fA2e10Ee6A223F8a684;
  //address private busd = 0x78867BbEeF44f2326bF8DDd1941a4439382EF2A7;
  //address private dai = 0x8a9424745056Eb399FD19a0EC26A14316684e274;
 
  address private crypto1 = 0x7ef95a0FEE0Dd31b22626fA2e10Ee6A223F8a684;
  address private crypto2 = 0x78867BbEeF44f2326bF8DDd1941a4439382EF2A7;
  address private crypto3 = 0x8a9424745056Eb399FD19a0EC26A14316684e274;
  
  //uint totalSum;

  constructor() {
    uniswapRouter = IPancakeRouter02(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
    
  }
  
  function convertEthToCrypto(uint cryptoAmount) public payable {
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 15; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!
    uniswapRouter.swapETHForExactTokens{ value: msg.value }(cryptoAmount, getPathForETH(crypto1), address(this), deadline);
    
    // refund leftover ETH to user
    (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "refund failed");
  }
                 
  function getPathForETH(address crypto) public view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
    path[1] = crypto;
    
    return path;
  }
  
  
  function getETH() public view returns(address) {
      return uniswapRouter.WETH();
  }
  
  // important to receive ETH
  receive() payable external {}
}
```

Here the `convertEthToCrypto` swaps one token and is a payable function. So in Remix I input a specific amount of WEI and the function swaps the token.

But how do I manage to swap multiple tokens at once?

Comment: Tried testing your code and it didn't work for me. In "cryptoAmount" I put 0.001, but I get an error:

transact to UniswapExample.convertEthToCrypto errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value" value="0.001" code=INVALID_ARGUMENT version=bignumber/5.5.0). Help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I would use swapExactTokensForTokens and call it as many as you want.
you can even create a loop to manage if you have many cryptos to swap or if it's always the same, hardcode the calls.
here is a quick example with DAI and USDT.
you can replace the tickers with variables and use a loop if you want.

```
address[] memory path = new address[](2);
path[0] = address(DAI);
path[1] = address(USDT);
UniswapV2Router02.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, msg.sender, block.timestamp);
```

Comment: Be careful with loops, as you must give an amountOutMin and the price of the token will vary with each iteration, this will make this parameter inaccurate and may give error due to insufficient amountOutMin.
And in case you set it too low then your operation is exposed to be sandwiched.